# How get meta from all users?

Tags: user-meta, users

I want to get all users with their respective data. I already get all the users:

```
$users = array();

$users_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 
    'role' => 'subscriber', 
    'orderby' => 'user_registered',
    'number' => 8,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'fields' => array('ID', 'display_name')
) );
$results = $users_query->get_results();
```

But I only get the data from user table:

```
object(stdClass)#3162 (10) {
      ["ID"]=>
      string(2) "44"
      ["user_login"]=>
      string(13) "usuarioprueba"
      ["user_nicename"]=>
      string(13) "usuarioprueba"
      ["user_url"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["user_registered"]=>
      string(19) "2016-10-13 16:27:56"
      ["user_status"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["display_name"]=>
      string(14) "Usuario Prueba"
    } ...
```

How do I get also the data from `usermeta` without having to use a loop like a `foreach`

Answer (score 2):

All the metadata should be there, you can access them with magic methods.

If you have a metadatum called with the key `shoes`, you can access it like this

```
$userObject->shoes
```

Answer (score 0):

This was under the [return fields parameter on WP_User_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Return_Fields_Parameter)

> 'all (default) or all_with_meta' - Returns an array of WP_User objects. Must pass an array to subset fields returned.
>
> *'all_with_meta' currently returns the same fields as 'all' which does not include user fields stored in wp_usermeta. You must create a second query to get the user meta fields by ID or use the __get PHP magic method to get the values of these fields.

So, unless this is outdated, it sounds like it's not directly possible.

Comment: Looking at the code of [`wp-includes/class-wp-user-query.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/class-wp-user-query.php#L188), it appears that (at least according to the comments) `all_with_meta` should return all the users with their metadata.